# Querying for JSON data in Oracle creates syntax error

Tags: sql, json, oracle

using Oracle documentation ([Link here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/condition-JSON_EXISTS.htm#ADJSN-GUID-8A0043D5-95F8-4918-9126-F86FB0E203F0)) I tried to query the table with JSON data for existance of some value.

Example JSON data in column looks like this:

> [{"id":"14843"},{"id":"14103"},{"id":"16632"},{"id":"14776"},{"id":"14658"},{"id":"14426"},{"id":"14838"},{"id":"14834"},{"id":"14804"},{"id":"14803"},{"id":"14802"},{"id":"14801"},{"id":"14779"},{"id":"14767"},{"id":"16013"},{"id":"15980"},{"id":"15979"},{"id":"15978"},{"id":"15977"},{"id":"15976"},{"id":"15975"},{"id":"15974"},{"id":"15973"},{"id":"15972"},{"id":"15971"},{"id":"15970"},{"id":"15969"},{"id":"15968"},{"id":"15967"},{"id":"15966"},{"id":"15965"},{"id":"15964"},{"id":"15963"},{"id":"15962"},{"id":"15961"},{"id":"15960"},{"id":"16012"},{"id":"15903"}]

I want to get row where this JSON data contains some particular value.
I tried query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE json_exists(JSON_COLUMN, '$.id?(@ == 16632)');
```

According to documentation the syntax is proper but Oracle SQL Developer gives me error

```
ORA-40442: Błąd składni wyrażenia ścieżki JSON
40442. 00000 -  "JSON path expression syntax error"
*Cause:    The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) path expression
           had an invalid syntax and could not be parsed.
*Action:   Provide JSON path expression with the correct syntax. Error at Line: 1 Column: 76
```

I even tried to copy `'$.LineItems?(@.Part.UPCCode == 85391628927)'` from documentation and it still gives the same error.
Can you tell me what is wrong with this syntax?

EDIT:
All the versions I tried (which all give the same error):

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE json_exists(JSON_COLUMN, '$.id?(@ == "16632")');
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE json_exists(JSON_COLUMN, '$?(@.id == "16632")');
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE json_exists(JSON_COLUMN, '$?(@.id == 16632)');
```

Comment: From what I understand parsing error is independent of data contained in the column, so statement COPIED FROM DOCUMENTATION shouldn't give syntax error, am I wrong?

Comment: try: SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE json_exists(JSON_COLUMN, '$.id?(@ == "16632")');

Comment: Which version are you using? I think that syntax isn't valid in [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions010.htm#SQLRF56664), so are you on 12cR2, which the doc link you provided is for? ([Changes in 12cR2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/changes.htm#GUID-873D2F6E-AEC9-499C-B81A-B0092DFE993C) include "JSON path expressions can now include filter expressions..").

Comment: Thank you Alex, it seems that I have 12.1.0.2.0 version, which is 12cR1, Any idea how to do the thing I need in 12cR1?

Comment: I guess `json_textcontains()` might work if you have the right indexes, but I'm not in a position to test and write something up, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Oct 12 10:48:43 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Oct 10 2017 22:52:08 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create table test_json(JSON_COLUMN clob, CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (JSON_COLUMN is json));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_json values('[{"id":"14843"},{"id":"14103"},{"id":"16632"},{"id":"14776"},{"id":"14658"},{"id":"14426"},{"id":"14838"},{"id":"14834"},{"id":"14804"},{"id":"14803"},{"id":"14802"},{"id":"14801"},{"id":"14779"},{"id":"14767"},{"id":"16013"},{"id":"15980"},{"id":"15979"},{"id":"15978"},{"id":"15977"},{"id":"15976"},{"id":"15975"},{"id":"15974"},{"id":"15973"},{"id":"15972"},{"id":"15971"},{"id":"15970"},{"id":"15969"},{"id":"15968"},{"id":"15967"},{"id":"15966"},{"id":"15965"},{"id":"15964"},{"id":"15963"},{"id":"15962"},{"id":"15961"},{"id":"15960"},{"id":"16012"},{"id":"15903"}]');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_json WHERE json_exists(JSON_COLUMN, '$.id?(@ == 16632)');

JSON_COLUMN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"id":"14843"},{"id":"14103"},{"id":"16632"},{"id":"14776"},{"id":"14658"},{"id
```

I guess @Alex Pool is right and you are not running 12.2

Comment: Yep, I'm running 12.1, any idea how to do this in 12.1?